# How can i call servlet on button click aem

Tags: servlets, aem

i have servlet

```
   @Component(service={Servlet.class},
        property={"sling.servlet.methods=get",
                "sling.servlet.resourceTypes=/content/wknd-events"})
public class MainServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet
{
    @Reference
    DemoInterfaceImpl demoInterface;

    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        demoInterface.redirectUser(request,response);
    }
}
```

demoInterface

```
    @Component(
        service= IDemoInterface.class,
        immediate = true)
public class DemoInterfaceImpl implements IDemoInterface {
    @Override
    public void redirectUser(final SlingHttpServletRequest req,
                             final SlingHttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        resp.sendRedirect("/content/we-retail/us/en.html");
    }
}
```

and i have my component

```
<a href="/content/wknd-events.html">
<button> go</button>
</a>
```

i want to redirect to /content/we-retail/us/en.html on button click but it doesn't work. I still go to /content/wknd-events.html. I don't understand where is my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your basic mistake is  here   `"sling.servlet.resourceTypes=/content/wknd-events"})`

The resourceType in Sling is the resourceType property set on the resources/nodes. So, if you register a servlet based on resourceType, it will get invoked only if you have the component or resource of that type. In your case , the servlet is registered with a content path as resourceType . Instead of sling.servlet.resourceTypes ; you can try `sling.servlet.paths` (e.g `"sling.servlet.paths=/bin/test"`) and register your servlet to a path. Instead of giving a href attribute in the `<a>` tag, write an AJAX call on the click event of the button and give the servlet path as the URL.

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',    
     url:'/bin/test',
     success: function(msg){
       <!-- some code -->   
     }
 });
```